# Old movie where a submarine is powered by a necklace crystal

Tags: story-identification, movie

As I was a kid, I watched this one movie where I have forgotten most of it, I want to watch that movie again and I am asking for your help. Here's what I remember in as much detail as possible:

A man thought to be dead after an aircraft accident that crashes his plane into the sea was found alive by our protagonists.

An old sub is powered by a glowing necklace crystal from a female character given to her by someone important to her, as you can see from the image below, the necklace is placed in the star spot in a compartment on the floor and the triangle thing starts spinning.

The main characters are looking for some more of these white glowing crystals and in the end, they found a whole cave full of them. Then, finally, the villain tried to use more of these crystals to power up the sub again but none of the chunks fit into the star slot, ending his life.

[image: Necklace placed in a star spot]

The time when I watched it but (it is very hazy, I may be wrong): 2002-2006

Comment: How old is "old"? 30s? 60s? 80s? Later? :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community!  This is a nice question, and the diagram is great, but if you looked at the [question guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) maybe you could fill in a few extra details?  It would help a lot if you told us approximately what year you saw the movie, for instance.

Comment: Jenayah, I forgot... sry
 DavidW, That's all I can remember.

Comment: No worries :) maybe you can still tell us roughly when you were a kid? That'll give us some "time frame" indication to search for!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Episode 3 of [Dinotopia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0233044/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt), not a movie but a TV mini-series.

> They know they need to find a way out but David says that there's none as Cyrus has left. Karl says that he won't get very far without the sunstone from Marion. The sub's engine sputters and Cyrus realizes that once again, Karl has crossed him once more. **He frantically dumps out a bag of sunstones and tries fitting in various ones into the slot but none fit.** He knocks over his pistol which hits the floor and fires a bullet which ricochets around the inside and then cracks the front glass causing sea water to seep in. The sea monster now heads in the direction of the sub. Cyrus looks back in horror as he sees the massive head of the eel cross the bow of his sub. Cyrus realizes that his fate is now sealed saying, "No, no..not like this." The eel turns away for a moment as Cyrus tries one last time with the controls to move the sub, but without the sunstone to power it, is dead in the water. Water now pours in and the inside is now rapidly filling with water as Cyrus strains to see what is the opening maw of the Dunkleosteus coming straight for him. The creature swallows the submersible whole.

You can see the show [here](https://archive.org/details/dinotopia-miniseries-episode-3), with the submarine scene starting at 42:00

Comment: That seems likely. Which would means 2002 is old. Which would mean I'm joining the "well, okay. Gotta get used to it, I'm old" club already... :(

Comment: @Jenayah Welcome to the club!

Comment: You sir, are a hero.

Comment: @HT30624700 - [Modesty forbids me from agreeing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)

Comment: It does not appear to have been swallowed whole. The rushing water and then the floating debris indicates that it was broken up quite badly.